# How to enforce joomla search upto one component data only

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

By default joomla(2.5) search module searches only article, categories, weblinks etc but i want to enhance the functionality to make it search table data from one of one component data leaving the other search criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling and little brain storming i found solution on my own, so i would like to share it with you.

```
In Joomla we have to create a plugin to enhance features of search
module.

If we want that the "search module" to search data from our custom
compenents then we have to create a plugin for that. This link is
very useful while creating  a joomla search plugin
"http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin".

once a plugin is created you need to zip the folder and then upload
your plugin through the joomla "Extension Manager" in the admin
panel.

If you want to have only search criteria from the component and not
articles, weblinks, categories etc "disable" these plugins.
```